# Using @alternatives in CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have started with the book Beginning in Java EE7, currently busy with the chapter on CDI. 
My Alternative class looks like below.

```
@Alternative
@ThirteenDigits
public class MockGenerator implements NumberGenerator {

@Inject
private Logger logger;

@Loggable
public String generatorNumber() {
    String mock = "MOCK-" + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt());
    logger.info("Generated mock : " + mock);
    return mock;
}
}
```

The other dependency class that I use is like below

```
@ThirteenDigits
public class IsbnGenerator implements NumberGenerator {

@Inject
private Logger logger;

@Loggable
public String generatorNumber() {
    String isbn = "13-84356-" + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt());
    logger.info("Generated ISBN : " + isbn);
    return isbn;
}

}
```

My beans.xml file looks like below.

```
 <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org.2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/sml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">

<alternatives>
    <class>com.narotech.MockGenerator</class>
</alternatives>
<interceptors>com.narotech.LoggingInterceptor</interceptors>
</beans>
```

My injection code is as follows.

```
@Inject 
@ThirteenDigits
private NumberGenerator numberGenerator;

public Book createBook(String title, Float price, String description) {
    Book book = new Book(title, price, description);

    book.setNumber(numberGenerator.generatorNumber());
    return book;
}
```

Now, I'm not sure why, but when I run my JUnit test, I get "13-84356-683584002" and not something like "MOCK-84356-683584002". Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong. Let me know if you need more information from me.

Comment: How do you initialize cdi in your test?

Comment: Just test using @Priority to activate your alternative. If it works problem comes from the beans.xml you provide for your test, otherwise, you have it's somewhere in the code....

Comment: Thanks. the @Priority annotation worked

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this issue. I simply added a @Priority annotation to the MockGenerator class.

Comment: But then what is the point of `@Alternative`? Seems to me it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

`@Priority` is one way to solve it, but you could have also used `@Specializes` as a simpler mechanism:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html#gkhpo